# C and global variables/functions

Tags: c, header, global, extern

I'm porting some C++ code I have. It works perfectly in C++, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I have "`a.c`" and "`b.c`". They both include "`a.h`", which in turn includes "`b.h`". The functions in "`b.c`" are declared in its header file (with the `extern` keyword) and one of them is called from "`a.c`". It compiles and runs, but the call never seems to go through (I even put a couple `printf()` lines in for diagnostic, but nothing happens).

I know I'm overlooking something simple, I just can't put my finger on what. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: pasting some simplified code:
EDIT 2: The call goes through, there was a library issue to fix. Now the index variable isn't incrementing, I think it might be a scope issue.

in "a.c"

```
    #include "a.h"
    ...
    int sSimDisp(void){
        buttons();
    printf("x = %04d\n", index);
        ...
    }
    int main(){
    ...
    while(1) {
        sSimDisp();
        ...
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

in "a.h"

```
    #ifndef a_H_
    #define a_H_
    ...
    #include "b.h"
    #include "c.h"
    int sSimDisp(void);
    int main(void);
    #endif /* a_H_ */
```

in "b.c"

```
    #include "a.h"
    ...
    int index = 0;
    void buttons(){
      printf("Entry to button subroutine.\n");
        index++;
        ...
    }
    void touchscreen(){
    ...
    }
```

in "b.h"

```
    #ifndef b_H_
    #define b_H_
    ...
    extern int index;
    //button handler
    void buttons();
    //touch screen handler
    void touchscreen();   
    #endif /* b_H_ */
```

Comment: Do you have `'\n'` at the end of your `printf` calls?

Comment: "with the extern keyword" - all functions are `extern` by default

Comment: Can you do a minimal example and show us? See e.g. http://sscce.org/

Comment: I'll slim down the code and paste it. and I only used "extern" on the variables, that was my mistake when posting.

Comment: Try to run it in a debugger, and step through the code to see what it does.

Comment: this might or might not be connected, but an empty parameter list in C means something completely different to an empty parameter list in C++ (ref b.c and b.h)

Comment: What is in `c.h` (which is included in `a.h`)? If I remove that include and all the `...`s, `buttons` gets called.

Comment: This isn't your problem, but if neither of the functions in `b.c` call  `sSimDisp` or `main`, then there's no reason to include `a.h` in `b.c`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete code example which compiles and exhibits the problem. With the current information, we can just guess. E.g. if the 3rd `...` is in fact `if (0)` the problem becomes obvious.

Comment: Ok, it's being called, there was an issue with the library I was using and the print function. The code is being run straight to hardware and there's no debugger. Now the problem is that some global variables don't seem to be incrementing properly, I'll update the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of int main(void) in a.h could well result in undefined behaviour.

There can only be ONE main in a program, and you don't put a prototype in the header.

Comment: Could you back up this statement with a reference please? I cannot imagine how an additional, consistent declaration of `main` could hurt.

Comment: From (C++ i think) Standard docs., 3.6.1.2 Main Function,

    It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main:

int main() { / ... / } and int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { / ... / }

It says nothing about permitting or not permitting declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with my code, the libraries are just really jacked up. I'm gonna grab the guys and we'll sort through the last changes to the repo. Thanks for the help, I just wanted to make sure it was nothing I did wrong.